# ZXing doesn't read 1D barcode in Android app

Tags: android, barcode-scanner, zxing

I am developing a new application which hopefully will use a barcode reader to scan and find books. I will then use the ISBN information to get more information.

The intents work and I can scan 2d barcodes ok but not the 1d barcodes of books which I know scan fine using the full application.

This is my code. I have tried it without putting the intent extras and it doesn't change anything.

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "ONE_D_MODE");
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

Is there something obvious I am missing? The settings in the app also are selected on 1d scanning only.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that using product mode worked perfectly. I don't know why I didn't try that earlier!

```
intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "PRODUCT_MODE");
```

Comment: Cool, glad to hear it, though I too don't know why ONE_D_MODE wasn't working for you. Should be just the same.

Answer (score 1):

(Probably easiest if I answer in just one place: http://code.google.com/p/zxing/issues/detail?id=574 )